# Expected a type error when trying to create a class method with parameter of another class after importing header files

Tags: objective-c, class

So basically I am creating 2 classes here:
Patient and Doctor

and what I want to do is that I want to create an instance method called "requestMedicationForPatient" that takes a patient instance as a parameter.
So I did something like this

```
-(void)requestMedicationForPatient: (Patient*) patient;
```

in the Doctor.h file.
and also I already imported Patient.h file in both Doctor.h and Doctor.m files.
Why doesn't it work?

Patient.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Doctor.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Patient : NSObject
@property NSString* name;
@property NSInteger age;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasValidHealthCard;

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString*) name andAge: (int) age;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Patient.m:

```
#import "Patient.h"
#import "Doctor.h"

@implementation Patient

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString*) name andAge: (int) age
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _age = age;
        _name = name;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Doctor.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Patient.h"
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Doctor : NSObject
@property (nonatomic)NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic)NSString* specialization;
@property (nonatomic)NSMutableSet* patients;
- (instancetype)initWithName: (NSString*) name andSpecialization:         (NSString*) specialization;
-(void)requestMedicationForPatient: (Patient*) patient;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Doctor.m:

```
#import "Doctor.h"
#import "Patient.h"
@implementation Doctor

- (instancetype)initWithName: (NSString*) name andSpecialization: (NSString*) specialization
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = name;
        _specialization = specialization;
    }
    return self;
}



@end
```

I should be able to create that method with a parameter of type Patient right ? But it says Expected a type.

Comment: We need to see the exact error message and also what line the message appears on.

Comment: -(void)requestMedicationForPatient: (Patient*) patient;  this line went wrong sayd expected a type..

Answer (score 0):

You are importing Patient.h into Doctor.h and you are importing Doctor.h into Patient.h. Always avoid such circular imports. Also avoid needlessly importing a header file in another header file.

Nothing in Patient.h references anything from Doctor.h so you should not be importing Doctor.h in your Patient.h file.

You should also remove the import of Patient.h from Doctor.h. To make the compiler happy, you can provide a forward reference to `Patient` using `@class Patient;`.

Your updated Doctor.h should be:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@class Patient;

@interface Doctor : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* specialization;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableSet* patients;

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name andSpecialization:(NSString*)specialization;
- (void)requestMedicationForPatient:(Patient *)patient;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```